# sql function : Data truncated for column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem with a SQL function that I retrieved on the web

```
CREATE DEFINER=`production`@`%` 
FUNCTION `distance terrestre`(lo_target float,la_target float,lo_ref float,la_ref float) 
RETURNS float
DETERMINISTIC
begin
  return (6366*acos(cos(radians(la_ref))*cos(radians(la_target))*cos(radians(lo_target)-radians(lo_ref))+sin(radians(la_ref))*sin(radians(la_target))));
end
```

I know it works because I have already used it on another data set.
The bug exists since I changed the source of the coordinates (it is a function of calculation of distance)

I therefore suspect formatting or decimal size.

After my error

Error

SQL query: Documentation

thanks

Comment: check all your TEXT and VARCHARs in `lo_target` see if it can handle large strings , also check for strings trying to be treated as numbers

Comment: How can I do this?